# Should `drop()` retain dimnames when dropping from array to matrix?

Tags: r, arrays

I noticed that `base::drop()` removes array dimension names if the dimensions don't have element-specific names:

```r
a = array(
  data = 1:12,
  dim = c(2,3,4),
  dimnames = list("test" = NULL, "test2" = NULL, "test3" = NULL))
a[1,,,drop = FALSE] |> dimnames()
#> $test
#> NULL
#> 
#> $test2
#> NULL
#> 
#> $test3
#> NULL
a[1,,,drop = TRUE] |> dimnames() # I think this is equivalent to `a[1,,,drop = FALSE] |> drop()`
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Is this intended behavior? I was expecting the output of `a[1,,,drop = FALSE] |> dimnames()` to be

```
#> $test2
#> NULL
#> 
#> $test3
#> NULL
```

Comment: That looks like a bug, and indeed many functions in base R do "forget" about `names(dimnames(.))`.  A notable example is `solve`.  If you've checked the documentation, then consider filing a [bug report](https://www.r-project.org/bugs.html).

Comment: Note that in the `dimnames()` documentation it states "It is possible that all [list] components are NULL: such dimnames may get converted to NULL." which seems to be the case here.